# Какое наиболее приемлемое решение счетчика просмотров на Django?

Tags: django

В общем, можно было бы обойтись и простым обновлением поля views у статьи. Понятное дело, что у такого способа однозначно будет ложная картина о просмотрах, но больше всего беспокоит нашествие какого-нибудь бота, который при желании намотает число до наиболее вмещаемого значения (у 32-битного числа там два с копейками миллиарда).

Поэтому из-за выше описанных причин встал вопрос, как более-менее избавиться от накрутки.

Думал о создании дополнительной таблицы, где вписывались бы ip пользователя и ссылка статьи, но это накладно постоянно ее дергать, особенно когда число посетителей вырастет.

Делать запросы к этой таблице через определенное время (каждые 5-10 минут) тоже не вариант. Пользователь зайдет на статью, где еще нет просмотров и не поймет, где его просмотр.

Далее... Насчет Яндекс Метрики и Google Analytics. Говорят, что просмотры с мобильных устройств не учитываются (хотя возможно уже работает).
Если учитываются, то является ли этот способ хорошим и считает ли он уникальных посетителей?

Что собственно хочу сказать в итоге. Не кидайтесь в меня помидорами, опыта как такового за плечами мало. Просьба помочь с определением, в сторону какой идеи двигаться. Возможно сможете что-то сами предложить или скинуть ссылку на какую-нибудь статью. Заранее спасибо.

**UPD. Более-менее определился со следующим вариантом (если есть замечания - пишите).**

models.py

```
class Article(models.Model):
    # ...
    views = models.BigIntegerField(default=0) # Чтобы уж точно не волноваться о превышении значения

class UniqueView(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField()
```

После чего еще надо будет настроить во views.py получение ip.

При просмотре страницы данные будут записываться в таблицу UniqueView. После этого можно считать количество ip для каждой статьи и записывать число в поле views модели Article.

Примерно каждую неделю или чаще очищать таблицу UniqueView. Выйдет вполне чистая статистика, т.к. цель стоит исключить простые накрутки при перезагрузке страницы.

Единственное пока не представляю как это все реализовать :D , так как еще ни разу не обрабатывал данные в базе по интервалам во времени.

Comment: Почти наверняка у вас не возникнет таких нагрузок, на которых дополнительная таблица стала бы тормозить :)

Comment: Значит все-таки в сторону доп. таблицы двигаться? А не сильно ли она большой выйдет, IP ведь придется хранить для каждой статьи. Скорее всего я сильно недооцениваю скорость БД, но почему-то кажется, что уже на 500-1000 посетителей возникнут проблемы.

Comment: Пока число записей в таблице не приблизится к нескольким миллионам или число запросов к этой таблице не станет больше десятка в секунду, беспокоиться не о чем)

Comment: @andreymal если речь зайдёт о дефолтной sqlite, там все гораздо печальней по опыту. :)

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич ну это уже ССЗБ :)

Comment: За несколько десятков запросов в секунду можно еще долго не беспокоиться, а вот про миллион ip все равно остается. Она [таблица] изначально обречена на постоянный рост. Рано или поздно их же наберется столько, и что в таком случае потом делать? Счищать ее?

Comment: Добавил в описание вопроса какого-то рода доработку идеи. Если есть замечания - пишите.

Comment: @Jimmy на моём основном сайте за четыре года набралось сто тысяч записей, не тормозит :) На совсем уж гигантских нагрузках (которых у вас не будет, я гарантирую это) можно воткнуть промежуточное кэширование актуальных данных в memcached или redis и тем самым снизить частоту обращения к таблице

Comment: Единственное замечание по Вашему коду, которое на самом деле решается далеко не тривиально - это как Вы считаете загрузку страницы. Знаете, чем визит плохого бота отличается от визита реального пользователя? Выполнением javascript и загрузкой статики. Это всё можно проанализировать сделав хитрый ajax и анализ логов http демона... Но вовсе не тривиально. А так Ваш счетчик ломается за 2 минуты с использованием например TOR.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич неужели до сих пор не распространены боты, использующие selenium/phantomjs? Неужели пользователей-параноиков, отключающих js, настолько мало, что ими можно пренебречь?

Comment: @andreymal пользователей параноиков, если это не хакерский форум - ресурс очень и очень мало. Ничтожно.  А таких ботов много, но вопрос цены/квалификации взломщика - накрутчика. Не каждый захочет с этим морочиться, и знаний не у всех хватит.

Comment: @andreymal у меня есть пара "дохлых" страниц, на которые заходят в основном боты. Вот там как раз вообще прозрачно, что ни один из них javascript не выполняет :)

Comment: Подмечу, у меня нет в планах ставить счетчик, продуманный на уровне ВКонтакте или иной крупной компании (но конечно по возможности исключить как можно больше проблем). Я еще правда не знаю, сработает ли такое решение на инкогнито-режиме в браузерах, но главное, чтобы я смог осилить предложенные решения, т.к. повторюсь, в таких вещах у меня нет как такового опыта.

Comment: А как с Яндекс Метрикой и Google Analytics дела обстоят? Через них лучше выйдет, не знаете?

Comment: @Jimmy, через них точно лучше. Вряд ли Вам удастся сделать лучше чем в Яндексе, там один вебивизор только чего стоит... И там учитывается куча всего, накрутка сильно осложнена, они знают что делают точно - опыта то поболее... Плюс постоянные обновления, идут в ногу со временем.

Comment: @Михаил Алексеевич, я так понимаю, Вы с чем-то из них уже работали. В таком случае у меня два вопроса. Он [ЯМ или GA] будет без проблем собирать статистику даже если пользователь отключит js? Можно ли вытягивать данные из статистики без размещения всяких баннеров? Если ответы положительные, то пойду собирать информацию по ним.

Comment: @Jimmy, с отключенными скриптами собирает весьма ограниченый обьем информации. Баннеры прошлый век, сейчас уже не требуют... Ставлю на все свои сайты....

Comment: Тогда предоставлю кому-то из них возможность считать просмотры. Читал про ограничение количества просмотров в сутки, но думаю до этого доходить будет не часто, но лимиты все равно заставляют беспокоиться) В любом случае спасибо!